# iOS - Centering a webview with constraints

Tags: ios, constraints

At some recent point I started building an existing app with Xcode 11 and the iOS 13 SDK, and got hit with a few of the changes to how layout works.

First of all was the change to default view controller presentation, which was easy enough to get around by setting it explicitly to fullscreen.

More frustrating, however, is the constraint-based layout I've been using to center a webview (`WKWebView`) on the view controller's main view. The complication is that I need to adjust the width of the webview programmatically.

This *was* working nicely previously by adjusting the constraint constant for the webview's leading and trailing constraints. Now, however, it doesn't seem to adjust properly. I've tweaked pretty much every variable in the layout trying to get back to the previous behavior without success.

The basic structure looks like this:

[image]

The webview's layout info is:

[image]

And the three horizontally impacting restraints are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

(I've tried changing the webview's layout to Automatic from Translates Mask, adding/removing autoresizing constraints, etc.)

Anything immediately jump out that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you modify your constraints by code ?

Comment: Yes, by setting `constraint.constant = n`.

Comment: just comment that line and then run your code. Stroybaord constraint is enough to manage.

Comment: As I noted, however, I need to adjust the constraints programmatically. This is to adjust the width/centering of the webview. (For whatever reason, trying to simply adjust the `webview.frame.width` has never worked.)

Comment: Either you can set webview constraints by programmatically or by storyboard. You are using both the approaches.

Comment: I hadn't seen any mention that this would no longer work in iOS 13.

Comment: (In fact, what other use is there for providing/allowing an identifier for a constraint in the storyboard other than to access it programmatically?)